# What are the best websites to use to look for a job in Substrate?

Tags: community

If I want to work with Substrate and this awesome community for a living, which websites are good places to look for substrate based roles?

(The corollary of this, if I want to hire someone, where should I be putting my job posting?)

Comment: Would you consider hackathons as a "website" to find jobs? If not, might we edit this post to be more broad at generally best ways to find a position? This could include other learning resources and things listed in https://substrate.io/ecosystem/square-one/ for example

Comment: I wouldn't have considered going to a hackathon to find a job, but that's the great thing about asking the question - if it's a way that roles are filled then going to hackathons is a great and fun answer.

Answer (score 7):

One community pairing of websites that are free to post in are:

- https://dotjobs.net for Polkadot (primary site)
- https://ksmjobs.net for Kusama (secondary, mostly the same as dotjobs)

These are maintained by [Stateless Money](https://stateless.money/)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can start looking here https://careers.substrate.io/jobs where most of the jobs are related to communities, parity also has some job offers https://www.parity.io/jobs/#jobboard.

Besides that, if you are not looking for open source projects, it is a little bit harder and I don't know any portal or hub for that.

Comment: Do note that the careers page is maintained by Parity and at least at the time of writing is mostly confined to posts from Parity, Web3, and those in the https://substrate.io/ecosystem/substrate-builders-program/ run by Parity.